# C# - Get value from dictionary with key - return property of object?

Tags: c#, object, dictionary, casting, key

I'm making a program which when a chemical symbol of an element is entered, it'll return information of that element onto the form. This is simple to do but it want to try and keep my code as efficient as possible.

My dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, object> alkaliM = new Dictionary<string, object>();
```

In my code also:

```
alkaliM.Add("Li", new AlkaliMetals.Lithium());
```

`elementSymbol` is my input string from the textbox

I'm trying to set `elementName.Text` to the property "`name`" of my `AlkaliMetals.Lithium` object. However, i can't simply put:

`elementName.Text = alkaliM[elementSymbol.Text];` as i can't set an object as a string. ("`Cannot implicty convert type "object" to "string"`")

Is there any way to set `elementName.Text` to `AlkaliMetals.Lithium.name` using only the key?

I have a separate file that has a main class `AlkaliMetals` and subclasses for each of the alkali metals like `Lithium`.

If my description doesn't make sense let me know and i'll try to explain what i mean.

Comment: `elementName.Text = alkaliM[elementSymbol.Text].name` ?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad that won't work as the dictionary is defined as `<string, object>`. it would need a cast.

Comment: Instead of using `object` as a reference type, use a base class from which every element derives. And access your name as: `alkaliM[elementSymbol.Text].name` simple

Comment: Why you store `System.Object` as `Value` in the first place? I guess there is a common base-type or interface which all implement.

Comment: @stuartd ahh right, i missed that it's `object` :/

Answer (score 3):

You can make all the sub classes in AlkaliMetals.cs implement an abstract class `CommonAbstractClass`
having the property `name`

Define you dictionary as `Dictionary<string, CommonAbstractClass>`

Then use your dictionary as follows `elementName.Text = alkaliM[elementSymbol.Text].name;`

Answer (score 0):

You can find the `name` property (**if you are absolutely sure it exists**) using dynamic cast:

```
elementName.Text = (alkaliM[elementSymbol.Text] as dynamic).name
```

---

However, a more efficient approach would be `Object Oriented Design`:

Define a class named `ChemicalElement`, add `name` property to it and then derive `Lithium` from `ChemicalElement`. This way you can write:

```
elementName.Text = (alkaliM[elementSymbol.Text] as ChemicalElement).name
```

---

Best solution is to define your dictionary like this:

```
Dictionary<string, ChemicalElement> alkaliM = new Dictionary<string, ChemicalElement>();
```

And then access the `name` like:

```
elementName.Text = alkaliM[elementSymbol.Text].name
```

Comment: This solution has worked. Quick question to @MarkBenovsky, how would i incorporate a "base abstract class". I'm kinda new to classes and objects in general and want to improve my abilities in these areas.